# What is wrong with this code (Simple LinkedList)

Tags: java, linked-list

So, I have been studied about linked list and had created this insert method.

```
private void insert(Node head, int data)
    {
        Node node = new Node(data);

        Node first = head;

        if(first == null)
        {
            head = node;
        }
        else
        {
            node.nextLink = first;
            head = node;
            //System.out.println(node.data);
        }
    }
```

and this traverse method

```
public void traversingLinkedList(Node head)
    {
        Node current = head;

        while(current != null)
        {
            int data = current.data;
            System.out.println(data);
            current = current.nextLink;
        }

    }
```

But it is not showing the node when I am inserting it.
The node data shows when I *uncomment* the print line in method *insert*.

for example,

LinkedList present is 10 -> 20 -> 30

after using insert(head,4)
I still get 10 -> 20 -> 30

though in the method insert when I uncheck the print method
it is showing first node data as 4

but when traversing it is not showing!

Why?

Comment: It seems you are inserting elements at the front. Your insert method should not return the new head element? (it is, node?)

Comment: It should. One mistake I found it is that in the main method I am setting Node head = ob1 
So, each time it is taking head = ob1 (ie 10) only.

How to fix this?

Comment: your insert method should return the value of new head which should update the head value of calling function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling a method in Java, the variables are copied, not referenced. This means that in your case, the variable `head` inside the `insert` method is only local and its modifications will not be visible outside the method.

Thus, since you are inserting elements at the front, the new head after the insertion is the node you have created (not the previous one) and you need to return it to update the next calls. Moreover, you could simplify the code of your insert method since you will always update the head value and the only conditional part is if there are more elements in the list or not.

```
private Node insert(Node head, int data)
{
    Node node = new Node(data);

    if (head != null) {
        node.nextLink = head;
    }

    head = node;

    return head;
}
```

In this case your main method should look like:

```
// LinkedList 10->20->30
head = new Node(30);
head = insert(head, 20);
head = insert(head, 10);

// Add the new 4 head: 4->10->20->30
head = insert(head, 4);
// Traversing
traversingLinkedList(head);
```

Answer (score 1):

`head` is a local variable, so assigning values to it inside your `insert(Node head, int data)` doesn't affect the `Node` passed to the method.

If your `insert` method is part of some `LinkedList` class, that class should hold a reference to the head of the list, and `insert` should assign to that reference. In that case you won't need to pass `Node head` as argument to `insert`.

The only way you can modify the list by using the passed `Node` argument is if the method would change the `nextLink` of that `Node`.

Comment: Alright! Got it. I found my mistake. In my main method, I had assigned Node  head = ob1 (ie 10)
So each time method called was taking head as that only. 
I now changed the return type of my insert method as Node and assigned head = insert(head,4) to update it there itself! 
Thank you.

Comment: @JoeBrown I'm not sure it's a good idea for the head of the list to be a local variable in your `main` method. Usually the head of the list is an instance variable of the LinkedList class. Only methods of the LinkedList class should be able to change the head of the list.